# aws ec2 describe-instances tag Value inverse search unexpected behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I can successfully list all instance that has a specific tag Value (just to clarify, I am interested only in the Value, not the Tag Key) with the following query:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
             --region eu-west-1  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?Tags[?Value==`eks`]]
```

The above lists only instances with a Tag value of `eks`, as expected.

However, when I do the opposite, and I try to list all instances without the `eks` Value by substituting `` Value==`eks` ``  for `` Value!=`eks` `` , it still returns the instances with the `eks` tag Value.

So just to confirm, when I run the following, it still returns the instance which has a Tag Value of `eks` along with all other instances.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?Tags[?Value!=`eks`]]'
```

This does not make sense to me. I would expect it to return only the instance *without* the `eks` tag Value.

Comment: If your instance has two tags, one "eks" and the other "something_else" then the second one makes the filter match the element, regardless of the first tag.

Comment: Okay. But In that case, why does the positive search match? Because the second tag would invalidate it, no?

Comment: You are always looking through the tags and finding an instance where *a* tag matches the filter criteria, not where *all* tags match, the first snippet finds the instance because the first tag matches, the second query finds the instance because the second tag matches. (at least that is how I understand it)

Comment: okay, so maybe I need to specify the key of the tag also, becuase I am searching for tags with key: project, that do not have the corresponding value: eks. I think then it would work right?